# Is it possible for the Azure Scheduler to send messages to Azure Service Bus in Avro format?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-scheduler

Is it possible for the Azure Scheduler (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/scheduler-get-started-portal#see-also) to send messages to Azure Service Bus in Avro format?

Answer (score 0):

Azure scheduler supports sending any raw input message to a servicebus queue. You should be able to format the message in Avor format manually when creating the job; but scheduler does not provide any formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The message sent from Azure Scheduler accepts string as the input [check the object for reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/scheduler/jobs/createorupdate#servicebusqueuemessage). As Avro format stores the JSON data in Binary format, the serialized JSON can be sent as the message from Scheduler. The message, after deserialization can be converted to Avro format in client side, where the message is received.